# Strike-through font style for CheckBox

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, checkbox, expression-blend

How can I set the font style of a Silverlight CheckBox to strike-through (<strike>sample text</strike>)? I use Expression Blend 4 and hoped it might be as easy as making the text **bold** or *italic*. But I didn't find a way so far. Alternative solutions for doing it in C# code are also welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only `TextDecoration` supported on the phone is `Underline` (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.textdecorations(v=vs.95).aspx).

If you want to create a strike through effect you will need to draw a line/path through the text yourself.

Comment: Bummer. But thanks for the MSDN link, it says it pretty clearly.